# Find Value of Decompiled Variable

Tags: c#, vb.net, virus

I'm a programmer with pretty basic abilities, and I located a suspicious looking file on a friend's computer. I emailed it to myself and opened it with the .NET reflector, just for fun on the off chance it worked. It did, and the code looks like it was initially written in C#/VB. The program looks to my untrained eye like a pretty basic stealer, grabbing all sorts of passwords from their standard directories. I also finally found what I was looking for; where all of this data is emailed to. I got it in my head that I could disable this email address and help others who have lost important data by contacting them. However, the email address and its password are stored as variables; Me.Information. What I really need is to find that variable, Me.Information. The program itself is simply enormous, filled with code that I barely understand in context. It's utterly unscrambled as far as I can see. No obfuscation. I've been searching in my free time for quite a while now, any pros out there who could lend a hand would be very much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you load it into visual studio and do a search for that variable?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I was hoping to keep it in a safer environment, an accidental f5 could be nasty. But I'll give it a shot... how do I do that from reflector?

Comment: just a idea, try export as project. Even if it is not working, you can now search with Notepad++ in all files of directory. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Export it to a project, and open it in some IDE (like visual studio). To address your concern about accidentally running the program, you can actually disable those run configurations in the project settings, so you have no chance of running/building it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If there was any possibility of you walking me through getting this .exe file into Visual Studio (I'm trying right now to no effect) I'd love that. I know it's a bit much, I'm just a little lost right now. I feel so close and yet so far :P
I tried to export it into a project in Reflector, and had trouble with that.

Comment: I recommend using JetBrains's decompiler. If you can get resharper, that can also decompile to a visual studio project - look those two up! Both by jetbrains, you should be able to get some form of free trial or something

Comment: AH! I got it. This is sort of exciting. I got it into a .vbproj, and stuck it in Visual Basic. I know you can't see the actual code... but... it sorta looks like there's an aray or something, me.information. 

I want to put the code in with proper tags, but I don't know how...
message.From = New MailAddress(Me.information(1))

Comment: Something to do with SQL...
            Dim num As Integer = Base.sqlite3_column_count(ugsomsbismrdBPQhqtxSimmmoadhWD)

Comment: Oh. Okay. I suppose there isn't much hope then. Shame. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Might be some hope there! I don't really know

Answer (score 0):

if you found the code section that sends the email out, you could just replace it with a messagebox that displays the address, rather than sending something to it. be careful though, dont wanna make a mistake and give away your passwords.

also, you can open up some .net files in notepad and see the strings. often times they will be easily readable... something like:

```
address = "me@somewhere.net"
```

(in code)

might be visible in notepad, although it may look like this:

```
m e @ s o m e w h e r e . n e t
```

(im not sure if they are actually 'spaces' but they do tend to display looking like spaces)

it could take awhile to search for all instances of "@" though, and it wont work unless they assigned it in a simple manner like my example... they may have constructed it to make it less visible

Comment: Ah, yes. The problem which I very much forgot to mention is that the program itself runs as a process (...virus.exe, really?), and never actually opens. I'm not sophisticated enough to figure that out.

Comment: the messagebox suggestion was assuming that you loaded it into visual studio... although it would be better to search through the source and find it, as opposed to running it, unless they obfuscated it, in which case it may be easier to run it. the 2nd suggestion only requires you to use "open with" and select notepad, and then search for all instances of "@" ...this could take awhile, though, and not guaranteed to work. although since you were already able to use refractor, you would be better off searching the source code for an @ sign, as opposed to the .exe file itself

Comment: There are so, so many files. How could I get it *all* in a text file?

Comment: And I do believe that its a lot harder to see than that. I really wish I could more easily trace these variables. :/